# Issue with other_offer_image_locator_3 in Amazon Selling Partner API

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm having weird issue with `other_offer_image_locator_3` attribute when sending to `PUT /listings/2021-08-01/items/{sellerId}/{sku}` Amazon SP API Endpoint. This is marketplace for Poland.

Attributes looks like this:

```json
{
    "purchasable_offer": […],
    "country_of_origin": […],
    "item_name": […],
    "fulfillment_availability": […],
    "manufacturer": […],
    "condition_type": […],
    "part_number": […],
    "product_description": […],
    "brand": […],
    "supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation": […],
    "warranty_description": […],
    "included_components": […],
    "compatible_devices": […],
    "merchant_suggested_asin": […],
    "finish_type": […],
    "color": […],
    "material": […],
    "recommended_browse_nodes": […],
    "item_length_width": […],
    "externally_assigned_product_identifier": […],
    "bullet_point": […],
    "main_product_image_locator": [
        {
            "media_location": {
                "link": "https://example.com/photo1.jpg",
                "width": 2000,
                "height": 2000
            },
            "marketplace_id": "A1C3SOZRARQ6R3"
        }
    ],
    "other_product_image_locator_1": [
        {
            "media_location": {
                "link": "https://example.com/photo2.jpg",
                "width": 2000,
                "height": 2000
            },
            "marketplace_id": "A1C3SOZRARQ6R3"
        }
    ],
    "other_product_image_locator_2": [
        {
            "media_location": {
                "link": "https://example.com/photo3.jpg",
                "width": 2000,
                "height": 2000
            },
            "marketplace_id": "A1C3SOZRARQ6R3"
        }
    ],
    "other_product_image_locator_3": [
        {
            "media_location": {
                "link": "https://example.com/photo4.jpg",
                "width": 2000,
                "height": 2000
            },
            "marketplace_id": "A1C3SOZRARQ6R3"
        }
    ],
    "other_product_image_locator_4": [
        {
            "media_location": {
                "link": "https://example.com/photo5.jpg",
                "width": 2000,
                "height": 2000
            },
            "marketplace_id": "A1C3SOZRARQ6R3"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm getting for every request error:

```json
{
    "sku": "…",
    "status": "INVALID",
    "submissionId": "…",
    "issues": [
        {
            "code": "4000001",
            "message": "Podana wartość atrybutu „other_offer_image_locator_3” jest nieprawidłowa.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "attributeNames": [
                "other_offer_image_locator_3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message says `The specified value of the attribute "other_offer_image_locator_3" is incorrect.`

I've checked:

- All image files are in .jpg format.
- All image paths are correct.
- I did not find in the Internet any suggestion what could be wrong.
- GPT AI and Notion AI gives dumb fictional JSON suggestions. ;P

What is wrong with this `other_offer_image_locator_3` attribute? It is the same as _1, _2 and _4 but with different digits in names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this by requesting Product Type Definitions Api (v2020-09-01). It will respond with a full schema in JSON, where all attributes are described with example values and description.

Photos object should look like this:

```json
"other_product_image_locator_4": [
  {
    "media_location": "https://example.com/photo5.jpg",
    "marketplace_id": "A1C3SOZRARQ6R3"
  }
],
```

**Important:** Amazon SP API accepts only URLs to their servers, so you will need S3 for image file storage.

Good luck with your integration! ;)

Comment: Good call - I was getting this error: {'issues': [{'code': '90000900', 'message': 'The attributes are invalid.', 'severity': 'ERROR', 'attributeNames': ['supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation'], 'categories': []}]} on a script to create listings that had worked for months.  I tried your suggestion to pull the product type definition and found that the requirement for 'supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation' on the category I was using (it had previously bee required in toy_figures)